# Porcentagem de gêneros de videogames no Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu quero mostrar a porcentagem de vários gêneros no meu código com o data set e ele está dando um o seguinte erro:

**ValueError: Lengths must match to compare**

A parte que tem o erro no meu código está assim, me ajudem a descobrir o erro

```
base = pd.read_csv ('gamestest.csv')
#base.Platform (a tabela excel possui uma coluna Platform)

porcen = base.DataFrame(base.Genre.unique())
totalPorcPlat = len(base)

for porc in porcen:
    contagemPorcen = base[base.Genre]==porcen].shape(0)
    print ('{}: {:0.2f}%'.format(porcen, contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcPlat))
```

Comment: Acho q a confusão está em `Platform` e `Platforms`. Se no for está `for Platforms in Platform:`, as últimas duas linhas deveriam usar `Platforms` no plural, e não `Platform`. Verifique a indentação também, acho que o código foi copiado errado na pergunta.

Comment: Mas no meu algoritmo existe a tabela chamada Platform

Comment: `base[base['Platform']==Platforms].shape[0]` e `.format(Platforms, ...`. Eu me referi à variável, e não à coluna.

Comment: Não deu certo, ainda retorna o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ei @AlexCiuffa eu tive mudar umas partes do meu código para melhor entendimento, a mudança que eu fiz é a porcentagem de gênero de videogames.

Answer (score 0):

Dada uma lista, `lista = ['plataforma 1', 'plataforma 1', 'plataforma 2']`

Quando fazermos:

```
for valor in lista:
    print(valor)
```

A saída é:

```
plataforma 1
plataforma 1
plataforma 2
```

No seu código está:

```
for porc in porcen:
    contagemPorcen = base[base['Platform']==porcen].shape(0)
    print ('{}: {:0.2f}%'.format(porcen, contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcPlat))
```

Mas o correto seria utilizar a variável `porc` (valor da lista) ao invés de `porcen` (lista inteira):

```
for porc in porcen:
    contagemPorcen = base[base['Platform']==porc].shape(0)
    print ('{}: {:0.2f}%'.format(porc, contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcPlat))
```

Ainda sim, existe um outro erro. Em vez de `.shape(0)`, o correto é `.shape[0]`.

#### EDIT

Para listar na ordem, é preciso armazenar todos os valores, ordenar e depois mostrar.

```
lista_porcentagens = []
for porc in porcen:
    contagemPorcen = base[base['Platform']==porc].shape[0]
    lista_porcentagens.append((contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcPlat, porc))

#ordenar a lista do maior para o menor    
lista_porcentagens.sort(reverse=True)
#printar os valores
for porcentagem, plataforma in lista_porcentagens:
    print ('{}: {:0.2f}%'.format(plataforma, porcentagem))
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora eu entendi o erro e está executando. Só que na linha `porcen = base.Genre.unique()` quando eu clico no explorador de variável do Spyder dá a seguinte mensagem: **Explorador de matrizes: object matrizes não é suportado no momento**.

Comment: Como faz para apresentar as porcentagems do maior para o menor (decrescente)?

Comment: Editei a resposta com este adendo.

Comment: `((contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcPlat, porc))` que cálculo é esse que não entendi

Comment: `for porcentagem, plataforma in lista_porcentagens:`
    `print ('{}: {:0.2f}%'.format(plataforma, porcentagem))` não está executando

Comment: De onde veio essa variável `porcentagem`?